# how to create customized messages in veins

Tags: omnet++, veins

I'm simulating a scenario in veins when I need to use customized messages with specific fields(it's not wsa,wsm or bsm).

to achieve this I defined .msg file and the .cc and .h file were generated successfully. I included .h file into the cc+ application code, the project builds without errors but when I launch the simulation I have the following error

Model error: WaveMac only accepts WaveShortMessages -- in module              (Mac1609_4) MyNetwork.rsu[0].nic.mac1609_4 (id=12), at t=0s, event #1

is it impossible to use customized messages in veins ?
if it's possible how to do it ?

Answer (score 0):

Feel free to amend as many fields as you want to one of the existing message types (or to inherit from them). The bit length of a message is configured separately (in the .ini file of a simulation), so how many fields are in a message has no impact on how the simulation behaves.

Comment: @Christopph Sommer  i used inheritance thanks for the response